# Does timely first aid speed up a wounded soldier's recovery?

Tags: xenonauts

A soldier will have to spend some time recuperating if they receive a serious wound during a mission. That time seems to depend on their remaining hitpoints, as they essentially recover those over the next few days.

Are "grey" HP, the ones that can be restored with a medikit, considered restored, lost, or something in between when the mission ends?

Answer (score 3):

The health points are considered lost. The benefit to using the medkit is preventing their health from going even lower.